# What are the intermolecular and intramolecular forces between Hg molecules/ atoms in liquid mercury?

Tags: bond, metal, intermolecular-forces

> Mercury is the only metal that is liquid at room temperature.

I know that metallic bonding exists between metal atoms but my knowledge is limited to metallic bonding found in solids. Will there be metallic bonding between $\ce{Hg}$ atoms in the liquid phase?

> Moreover, there will be London dispersion forces between the $\ce{Hg}$ molecules.

Does mercury liquid only have metallic bonding as the intramolecular force and London dispersion force as the intermolecular force?

If liquid mercury (with both metallic bonding and LDF) is compared with a hypothetical liquid that has hydrogen bonding along with LDF, will the boiling point of mercury be higher than the aforementioned hypothetical liquid?

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/3996/do-metallic-bonds-contain-london-dispersion-forces

Comment: Mercury is, at best, a fair conductor of heat and electricity.  See [this earlier answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13667/why-does-mercury-have-low-melting-and-boiling-points/13671#13671) for an explanation of mercury's physical properties.

Comment: @ron I understand. Can I conclude that liquid mercury only has LDF as intermolecular force based on these links?

Comment: @Peregrine  Yes.